# cocos2d Isometric map tutorial

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, isometric

just wondering if anyone knows of a good tutorial for isometric cocos2d maps? Haven't found a really good one for isometric, only orthogonal.

I can't get proper y co-ord's on the map.

Answer (score 6):

The book "Learn Cocos2d Game Development with IOS 5" by Steffen Itterheim and Andreas Löw has an excellent chapter on Isometric Tile Games (Chapter 11 I believe). It's worth checking out in my opinion.

Another open source 2D isometric game using cocos2d that you might find useful:
https://github.com/lozarcher/KnightFight

Comment: +1 for recommending my book. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, KnughFight is definatly good for the isometric part.

Comment: This is really helpful for me. Trying to design a new isometric cocos2d game too!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't EXACTLY what you are looking for, but the section on Isometry, though it is ActionScript3, may prove to be helpful in figuring out your coordinate issues.

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/

Just scroll down to the section on 'Isometry', as I previously noted. Good luck!